# Ionic crystals and conduction of electricity?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Why do solutions of sodium chloride conduct electricity but crystals of sodium chloride do not?

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia or other sites yourself ,  solid sodium chloride versus solutions https://www.quora.com/Why-does-sodium-chloride-solution-conduct-electricity

Comment: A crystal of NaCl is a lattice of sodium cations and chloride anions. Both are spatially fixed in the lattice and not free to move. Without mobile charge carriers no current can be conducted. But dissolved NaCl *dissociates* into very mobile solvated sodium cations and chloride anions. With mobile charge carriers present, NaCl solutions are highly conductive.

Answer (score 1):

In a solid, we need free electrons for conduction, as positive ion cores are fixed at their lattice sites. In a sodium chloride crystal, the $Na^+$ and $Cl^-$ ions are held together by the electrostatic attractive force between the two ions. It is this strong attractive force that keep the crystal hard. The electrons are tightly fixed at their lattice sites. So there is no charge in the $NaCl$ crystal qualified for conduction.

In the aqueous state, the $NaCl$ dissociates into $Na^+$ and $Cl^-$ ions and hence the solution is polar since the solvent dissolving it (water) is polar too. The presence of $H^+$ and $OH^-$ ions in the solution weakens the electric attractive force between the $Na^+$ and $Cl^-$ ions, thereby increasing their separation distance. By applying a suitable electric field, you an overcome this lesser attraction, thereby causing the ions to displace under the field, resulting in a conduction.